# get first file created into folder and run it ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, find, command

The following command try to get the first one file create at folder name ssh run it then delete it

```
find /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/*.t -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head
```

result two files i try to get just first one

```
2017-04-04+12:57:08.7890000520 /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/1-58707.t
2017-04-04+12:55:01.9810000520 /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/2-58712.t
```

am looking to run it with terminal ssh command

**Update**

with this command

```
find /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/*.t  | sort -r | head -n 1
```

i get last file name

```
/home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/2-58712.t
```

need to run then delete file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used xargs to run first and then xargs rm to delete

```
    find /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/*.t   -type f    | sort -r | head -n 1   | xargs sh
    find /home/buzzst/public_html/ssh/*.t   -type f    | sort -r | head -n 1   | xargs rm
```